# Magento - exporting product blank screen

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I'm using default profile for magento product export.  When i click the run profile, I get a blank screen.  I have 500 products in the db.  Also, I'm not able to export the product stocks, but I'm able to export customers. I'm using magento 1.7 version.  My `.htaccess` file. memory_limit is 128M

```
max_execution_time 18000
```

Please help.
I`m new to magento so...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the log files at /var/log and your wbeserver log files. They'll definitely tell you what's wrong. It looks like either not enough memory, execution time limit or something like that. But without to check the logs, we all have to guess. ;)

Comment: in mai sysem.log  "                                              2013-04-21T11:01:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: n  in /app/design/frontend/default/mythem/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml on line 392
2013-04-21T11:01:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: n  in /app/design/frontend/default/mythem/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml on line 407
2013-04-21T11:01:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: n  in /app/design/frontend/default/mythem/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml on line 411 "

Comment: my cod in option.phtml line 392 `<?php if (($PID == "rame") && ($n=="1")){ ?>'    line 407 `<?php if (($PID == "rame") && ($n=="5")){ ?>`   line 411 `<div class="optiune<?php  echo $n++; ?> desc <?php $title = $_option->getTitle();$t=str_replace (" ", "-", $title); echo $t;?>">`

Answer (score 0):

500 indicates a response timeout, meaning that magento isn't done with importing when the servertimeout kicks in.

The maxing the execution time doesn't mean the server will wait for it.

I suggest you import from command line since it's faster and doesn't produce timeouts. If you don't have this option try to tell apache to wait longer

Comment: Hello Soundz. 500 Is an apache response code for Internal Server Error, Commonly caused by a script creating an non recoverable error. Syntax error etc. The post however refers to 500 products not a 500 error code. You are correct though that importing via the command line should yield better results as its not a process constrained within another process. E.g. php running via Apache its php running in its own thread with more resource.

Answer (score 0):

This function in class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Parser_Product has a loop  foreach ($entityIds as $i => $entityId) {
So place some Mage::log() code there and get counter,memory usage and peak memory usage.
As if its because of memory or timeout then atleast this loop would have run few times.
If its memory issue then either increase memory and recheck.Also on times had seen unwanted attributes not removed from cart that too results in higher memory consumption.
If its time issues increase time.If increasing time or memory is a constraint then you will have to export fewer products at a time.

```
public function unparse()
    {
        $entityIds = $this->getData();

        foreach ($entityIds as $i => $entityId) {
            $product = $this->getProductModel()
```